# What is the most performance effective way to create a sitemap.xml for any CMS system?

Tags: web, content-management-system, sitemap, content-management

We want to implement a sitemap.xml feature in out CMS system.  There is some argument within our developers that this feature will impact performance due to each time a change is done in the Content a full list of links of the site needs to be created and placed in the sitemap.xml.

The idea is that each time a public viewing page is edited or added it is immediately added to the sitemap.xml making it up to date with the site.

While you are answering, and if you have time, what other CMS system open or not have built-in sitemap generation?

Thanks,

Comment: You might just consider making your URLs SEO-friendly. As I understand it, a sitemap isn't nearly as effective for SEO as setting up your website to be actually crawlable. I have an almost totally javascript website, and I made a sitemap and it didn't work so well. Eventually, I implemented static pages that mimic the javascript pages, and that did wonders for my rankings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the sitemap every time you update your CMS will definitely create performance issues, because sitemaps tend to be large, and costly to generate (from a CPU & disk i/o perspective).

What I would do is:
 1. map out the structure of your site
 2. determine which areas you need to link to in the sitemap
 3. add the name of the sitemap index to your robots.txt file
 4. write a script that will read from the database and generate static xml sitemap files
 5. create a cron job that will re-run this script on a regular basis
 6. submit your sitemap url to the search engines

Answer (score 2):

For the CMS-powered sites I work on, with 70,000 to 350,000 pages/folders each, we typically regenerate the sitemap XML once every 24 hours. We've never had any problems with that. Unless your site is as popular as Stackoverflow - and Google recognizes that it gets updated as much as SO - it won't re-crawl your site often enough to justify having a fully updated sitemap file.

Comment: This is a long shot (after 3 years!) - do you simply write the sitemap.xml to disk, cache it, or keep it in the DB?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony those sites run on SharePoint, which is a document database. So it is very convenient for throwing one-off documents like this directly into the document/CMS repository.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind google doesn't read your sitemap that often, its safe to re-generate on a cron job every day, so if you schedule a rebuild of it each evening in the quiet hours, google will pick the changes up next time you poll.

Answer (score 0):

We work with 1000s of relevant urls at our startup (Epiloge). As people said here and elsewhere, you want to have a static sitemap.xml which gets regularly updated (every day or every few days) and thus include all new relevant urls.

If you are working in a Javascript environment and don't want to use any libraries or frameworks, look at this article here for a plain Javascript solution to create a sitemap accessing a database, getting all the urls, then creating the xml and getting you the file - which you can then plug into your site structure.

https://www.epiloge.com/how-to-generate-a-sitemapxml-with-javascript-for-dynamic-page-urls-296c42