# How to make search engines index my dynamically created webpages?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to web developing. I am creating a website which can search data from `mysql` database. I have created `mysql` with items and its information like this.

> | id | items | information |

I have a search box that appears on every web pages where users search the term item and get the information. The request goes to the server through `$_GET` method where through `SQL` queries finds the information and gets the result.

My question is each items are only found when a user search in the search box and `unique url` is created like **example.com/?q=item** when user search for the item. These urls can be random so there is no way google would find what my database contains. So how can I make google to index each item that is in my database so the user can find the item in the search engine?

I thought to create static web pages for each item but it would be time-consuming and unnecessary. So please help.

Comment: google " site map"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099393/sitemap-on-a-highly-dynamic-website

Comment: Wow, Thanks.. I will do some research on site map.